# How to set ReferenceField value of mongoengine in mongodb shell?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, shell

this is my 2nd day with mongo. I am working with django + mongoengine.
structure of my article document is like this:

```
class Article(Document):
    title = StringField(required=True)
    content = StringField(required=True)
    comments = ListField(ReferenceField(Comment))
    author = ReferenceField(MUser, required=False)
```

I can set value of author from django shell, but i cant find a way to set this author field value (which will be a MUser object).
I have tried this:

```
db.article.update({
    'title' : 'asdasdasdasd'
}, {
    $set : {
        'author' : db.m_user.find({
            'email' : 'vsp@gmail.com'
        })
    }
})
```

but this does something that i dont get, when i do `db.article.find()` i get this result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57153cc2aec9680bc327bedb"),
    "title" : "asdasdasdasd",
    "content" : "",
    "author" : {
        "_mongo" : {
            "slaveOk" : false,
            "host" : "127.0.0.1",
            "defaultDB" : "",
            "promptPrefix" : "",
            "authStatus" : {
                "authRequired" : true,
                "replSetGetStatus" : false,
                "isMaster" : true
            },
            "_readMode" : "commands",
            "_writeMode" : "commands"
        },
        "_db" : {
            "_mongo" : {
                "slaveOk" : false,
                "host" : "127.0.0.1",
                "defaultDB" : "",
                "promptPrefix" : "",
                "authStatus" : {
                    "authRequired" : true,
                    "replSetGetStatus" : false,
                    "isMaster" : true
                },
                "_readMode" : "commands",
                "_writeMode" : "commands"
            },
            "_name" : "mblog"
        },
        "_collection" : {
            "_mongo" : {
                "slaveOk" : false,
                "host" : "127.0.0.1",
                "defaultDB" : "",
                "promptPrefix" : "",
                "authStatus" : {
                    "authRequired" : true,
                    "replSetGetStatus" : false,
                    "isMaster" : true
                },
                "_readMode" : "commands",
                "_writeMode" : "commands"
            },
            "_db" : {
                "_mongo" : {
                    "slaveOk" : false,
                    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
                    "defaultDB" : "",
                    "promptPrefix" : "",
                    "authStatus" : {
                        "authRequired" : true,
                        "replSetGetStatus" : false,
                        "isMaster" : true
                    },
                    "_readMode" : "commands",
                    "_writeMode" : "commands"
                },
                "_name" : "mblog"
            },
            "_shortName" : "m_user",
            "_fullName" : "mblog.m_user"
        },
        "_ns" : "mblog.m_user",
        "_query" : {
            "email" : "vsp@gmail.com"
        },
        "_fields" : null,
        "_limit" : 0,
        "_skip" : 0,
        "_batchSize" : 0,
        "_options" : 0,
        "_cursor" : null,
        "_numReturned" : 0,
        "_special" : false
    }
}
```

I managed to set similar situation from django shell, and that record shows neatly what author is , like this..

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57153ae9aec9680a8ae8f5a6"),
    "title" : "sdd",
    "content" : "eer",
    "author" : ObjectId("576fff2daec96854d8bff581"),
    "comments" : [ObjectId("5770282faec968640568f4ce")]
}
```

How do i achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongo shell we cannot use sub-queries in a kind os SQL like syntax.

To solve that we could do:

```
var author = db.m_user.find({
        'email' : 'vsp@gmail.com'
    }).limit(1).toArray()

    db.article.update({
        'title' : 'asdasdasdasd'
    }, {
        $set : {
            'author' : author[0]._id
        }
    })
```

Any comments welcome!